# Using arduino Serial object at the same time using directly USART register in the same code?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, interrupt

When I compile this code ;

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h> 
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <util/delay.h>
volatile int state_Led = LOW;  

int SerialVal_;

void setup()
{    
  #define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
  #define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)
   UBRR0H = (uint8_t)(UBRR_VALUE>>8);
   UBRR0L = (uint8_t)UBRR_VALUE;
   UCSR0B |= (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);   // Turn on the transmission, reception, and Receive interrupt 
  UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00);   
   interrupts();   
}

int c = 0;
int b;

void loop()
{  
  if(Serial.available() > 0); // Error Line
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{ 
 cli(); 
  while(!(UCSR0A&(1<<RXC0))){};
  c= UDR0;  // clear the USART interrupt
  UDR0 = c + 0x0A;    

    sei();
}
```

I get the error of **"C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp:115: multiple definition of `__vector_18'"**

To sum up, if I use interrupt with USART interrupt vector I can't use simple Serial.xxx class methods for a reason that I don't know. I know lots of people are having the same problem. If someone berings the solution, that would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using both the interrupt *and* polling via `Serial`?

Comment: Interrupt sends velocity reference input. But I need to control two motors separately. So I need some special char to change between motor 1 and 2. I couldn't do it with detailed c and decided to use simple IDE commands as well.

Comment: That doesn't at all answer my question. Polling is redundant if you're using the interrupt.